# Missing Repository Dropdown option "Settings" for a specific user

Tags: github, settings

[image]

[image]

One User A has the option to view settings, User B doesn't.
They both have the same member role in the organization and can both fork/write/pull/push/etc to the repositories in the organization.  How can I enable User B to also have access to view/modify settings for the repo?

Thanks!

Comment: Settings is an admin role for a given repo so i would see if there is a role you are perhaps missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. the problem was I made the repo and had access to settings.. even though I'm not an admin user.